# Find the minimium point of a function $f(x, y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

The function is $f(x,  y)=\sqrt{42x^2+82x+52y+8xy+11y^2+86}$. This might be very inconvenient to work with so I decided to make it $f^2(x, y)=42x^2+82x+52y+8xy+11y^2+86$. Using a 3D calculator, I found out that there is a minimum point. So the next step should be to calculate $\nabla f^2(x, y)$ right? What is it, and what is the minimum value?

Comment: Have you studied quadratic form in linear algebra? if so, you can use that method to find the min value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can complete the square and write $$(f(x,y))^2=42\Bigg(x+\frac{2}{21}y+\frac{41}{42}\Bigg)^2+{223 \over 21}\Bigg(y+\frac{464}{223}\Bigg)^2+{1 \over 446}$$
You should now see that $f(x,y)$ attains a minimum value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{446}}$ at $(x,y)=\Big(-\frac{347}{446},-\frac{464}{223}\Big)$.